# FluentValidation of a model

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Is this possible to validate a model and return an display a message for a model class using fluent assertion . I want to be able to validate the DistancePoint values.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{distanceMethod}/{measureUnit}")]
    public ActionResult<DistanceResponse> Get(DistanceMethod distanceMethod, MeasureUnit measureUnit,
        [FromQuery] double point1Latitude, [FromQuery] double point1Longitude,
        [FromQuery] double point2Latitude, [FromQuery] double point2Longitude)
    {
        var point1 = new DistancePoint
        {
            Latitude = point1Latitude,
            Longitude = point1Longitude
        };
        var point2 = new DistancePoint
        {
            Latitude = point2Latitude,
            Longitude = point2Longitude
        };
```

This is how I tried to implement it.

```
   public class DistancePointValidator:AbstractValidator<DistancePoint>
    {
        public DistancePointValidator()
        {
           RuleFor(x => x.Latitude).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(-90).WithMessage("Latitude can not be greater than -90");
           RuleFor(x => x.Latitude).LessThanOrEqualTo(90).WithMessage("Latitude can not be less than 90");
           RuleFor(x => x.Longitude).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(-180).WithMessage("Longitude can be greater than 180");
           RuleFor(x => x.Longitude).GreaterThan(180).WithMessage("Longitude can be less than 180");
        }
    }
```

And i registered the class in the startup file.

```
                 services
                .AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddFluentValidation(cfg => { cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<DistancePoint>(); });
```

Thanks

---

Part 2: The issue I am now facing is that validationPoint2 fails because the value is to big, it goes is the validationPoint2.IsValid condition but the error message is empty. When I inspect the validationPoint1 it has the error message.

```
        var validationPoint1 = _validator.Validate(point1);
        var validationPoint2 = _validator.Validate(point2);

        if (validationPoint1.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(validationPoint1);
        }

        if (validationPoint2.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(validationPoint2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to inject the validator to your contoller:

```
        private IValidator<DistancePoint> _validator;

        public YourControllerController(IValidator<DistancePoint> validator)
        {
            _validator = validator;
        }
```

and then in the `Get` method validate your variables like this:

```
            var validationResult = _validator.Validate(point1);
            if (!validationResult.IsValid)
            {
                // validation failed
            }
```

Comment: Hi. The issue i am having now is that when i validate the second point when I go to return the error message it is contained within the validationPoint1.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood corretly, could share the code, and describe the problem?

Comment: Does this make sense to you?

Comment: you missed the `!` in the `if` condition, it should be `if (!validationPoint1.IsValid)` - meaning that the validation failed, then you return `BadRequest`

Comment: Yes i understand that, When i have point one with a higher than 180 longitude it fails but the error message is contained with point2 . Thats what i dont understand